# Address Locator Only Fails with Suggestions Enabled

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geocoding

I am currently trying to create a General Single Field Address Locator in ArcMap 10.3.1. I can create the locator fine without the suggestion option enabled, but with it’s on it gives me the Error 000042. I have already removed special characters, and any duplicate names. I also tried saving off our network, in case of permissions issues to no avail. The error occurs when it is running the “Building suggestions index (merging data)…”

Are there any ideas out there what might be causing this? 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to this question can be found here: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/164349

There was a patch to install to fix this issue.